# Pass Parent reference to Dynamically Created Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic, aura-attribute, reference

I'm trying to create a lightning component ("filterPanel") that would dynamically create some child components ("customFilter")
I would like to pass the parent to children to avoid communicating with events.
I tried

```
    Parent
     $A.createComponent('c:customFilter',{parent: this},function(){}];
    Child filter
      <aura:attribute name='parent'  type='Object'    />
      var parent = component.getReference("v.parent");
```

but the parent is always empty object in child context.
How can I achieve my goal?
thanks

Comment: you can pass the parent's attribute reference to the dynamic child component (child should have equivalent attribute to hold onto parent's attribute reference).The idea of passing `this` won't work.

Comment: If you really don't want tight coupling between parent and child components.I would recommend to use component events

Comment: I do agree with the event but it doesn't always make sense. In my case I have a dropdown and dropdown entry components. They will always be tightly coupled and communicating via events makes little sense.

Comment: Then why not pass the parent's attribute to the child component.But if really want to invoke a parent's method from child, am afraid you need to use events

Answer (score 2):

This is not recommended as it is kind of a hack, but you can pass a callback from the parent to the child. Locker Service does not currently prevent this from working.

You can try something like this:

Create an attribute (I used string, but other types might work) to use as the callback:

```
<aura:attribute aura:id="callbackattr" name='callback'  type='Object'/>
```

In the parent:

```
$A.createComponent('c:customFilter',
                   {callback: function(){
                                alert("Hi from the parent");
                              }
                   },
                   function(){}];
```

Then, in your child handler or controller:

```
var callback = component.get("v.callbackattr");
if (callback){
    callback();  //should say "Hi from the parent"
}
```

It's a bit hacky, but it's worked for me before. I actually use events now, but this is quicker, for sure.

EDIT - it still works:

[image]